# Can I use prefetch_related to cache filtered querysets?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am using DRF to serialize some related models.  In my toy example below, assume that each author can have a million books.  Clearly doing a db query for all "good" books and then another db query for all "bad" books is inefficient.

This post [http://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/] offered some suggestions regarding `prefetch_related`.  But I found that this only helped when I made subsequent calls to `.books.all()` rather than `.books.filter()` as happens in the properties below.

Is there any *automatic* way in Django to cache the books queryset and *not* have subsequent filters to it hit the database again?

Here is some code:

**models.py:**

```
class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  @property
  def good_books(self):
    return self.books.filter(is_good=True)

  @property
  def bad_books(self):
    return self.books.filter(is_good=False)


class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  is_good = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="books")
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ("title",)

class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Author
    fields = ("name", "good_books", "bad_books",)

  good_books = BookSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source="good_books")
  bad_books = BookSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source="bad_books")

  @staticmethod
  def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
    queryset = queryset.prefetch_related("books") 
    return queryset
```

**views.py:**

```
class AuthorViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
  serializer = AuthorSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Author.objects.all()
    queryset = self.get_serializer_class().setup_eager_loading(queryset)
    return queryset
```

Thanks.

---

**edit:**

Using `Prefetch`:

```
@staticmethod
def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
  queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch("books", queryset=Book.objects.filter(is_good=True), to_attr="good_books"),
    Prefetch("books", queryset=Book.objects.filter(is_good=False), to_attr="bad_books"),
  )
  return queryset
```

This still gives me extra db hits for the calls to `filter`.

Comment: Yes, you can use **`Prefetch`** objects: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't seem to help.  I will edit the code to show you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it in model's property, which will be evaluated for each author separately, you can do prefetch on view level and use `Prefetch` with `to_attr` argument:

```
class AuthorViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
  serializer = AuthorSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Author.objects.prefetch_related(
      Prefetch('books', queryset=Book.objects.filter(is_good=True), to_attr='good_books'), 
      Prefetch('books', queryset=Book.objects.filter(is_good=False), to_attr='bad_books')
    )
    return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate your queryset first, in order to be cached. From docs [caching and querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets)

So instead of

```
return queryset
```

you could do

```
return [queryset]
```

Be aware that in certain cases querysets are not cached.